# Difference in Outputs when viewing an array in Python 2.7

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

Here I have 1 column of my MATLAB Data:

```
raw_data
10
-2.77738418373534e+242
3.68340627929942e+23
-1.66594278761299e+94
NaN
-2.77738418373534e+242
3.68340627929942e+23
-1.66594278761299e+94
NaN
2.67810000000000e-319
NaN
```

Here is the script which takes it as input:

```py
 nb_msg = int(raw_data[0, col])
 uint8_data = np.array(raw_data[1:1+nb_msg, col]).view(dtype=np.uint8)
```

The result is:

```
>>> np.array(raw_data[1:1+nb_msg, col]).view(dtype=np.uint8)

array([181, 211,  68, 242, 127, 211,  68, 242, 182, 127, 211,  68, 242,
127, 211,  68, 183, 242, 127, 211,  68, 242, 127, 211, 184,  68,
242, 127, 211,  68, 250, 127, 185, 211,  68, 242, 127, 211,  68,
242, 186, 127, 211,  68, 242, 127, 211,  68, 187, 242, 127, 211,
68, 242, 127, 211, 188,  68, 242, 127, 211,  68, 250, 127, 189,
211,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 210,  68, 242, 127, 132,  68,
250, 127], dtype=uint8)
```

However, when I explicitly specify it as such:

```
np.array([-2.77738418e+242,  3.68340628e+023, -1.66594279e+094,np.nan, -2.77738418e+242,3.68340628e+023,-1.66594279e+094,np.nan,2.67808283e-319,np.nan]).view(dtype=np.uint8)
```

the result becomes:

```
> > >np.array([-2.77738418e+242,  3.68340628e+023, -1.66594279e+094,np.nan, -2.77738418e+242,3.68340628e+023,-1.66594279e+094,np.nan,2.67808283e-319,np.nan]).view(dtype=np.uint8)

array([ 24, 135, 204, 241, 127, 211,  68, 242, 163, 109, 227,  68, 242,
127, 211,  68, 112, 139,  68, 212,  68, 242, 127, 211,   0,   0,
0,   0,   0,   0, 248, 127,  24, 135, 204, 241, 127, 211,  68,
242, 163, 109, 227,  68, 242, 127, 211,  68, 112, 139,  68, 212,
68, 242, 127, 211,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 248, 127, 189,
211,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
48, 127], dtype=uint8)
```

What is this difference attributed to?

I initially thought that the mantissa difference between MATLAB Data, and my manual entries was doing this. But it is worth noting that this is what Python returns:

```
>>> np.array(raw_data[1:1+nb_msg, col])

array([-2.77738418e+242,  3.68340628e+023, -1.66594279e+094,
                    nan, -2.77738418e+242,  3.68340628e+023,
       -1.66594279e+094,              nan,  2.67808283e-319,
                    nan])
```

which is the same as explicitly specified array.

Answer (score 0):

The mantissa difference in the data and my manual entry causes the difference in uint8 representation.

```
>>> np.array([-2.77738418e+242,  3.68340628e+023, -1.66594279e+094,np.nan, -2.77738418e+242,3.68340628e+023,-1.66594279e+094,np.nan,2.67808283e-319,np.nan]).view(dtype=np.uint8)
array([ 24, 135, 204, 241, 127, 211,  68, 242, 163, 109, 227,  68, 242,
       127, 211,  68, 112, 139,  68, 212,  68, 242, 127, 211,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0, 248, 127,  24, 135, 204, 241, 127, 211,  68,
       242, 163, 109, 227,  68, 242, 127, 211,  68, 112, 139,  68, 212,
        68, 242, 127, 211,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 248, 127, 189,
       211,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
       248, 127], dtype=uint8)
```

Changing the first element of the array as such, shows the expected result:

```
>>> np.array([-2.77738418373534e+242,  3.68340628e+023, -1.66594279e+094,np.nan, -2.77738418e+242,3.68340628e+023,-1.66594279e+094,np.nan,2.67808283e-319,np.nan]).view(dtype=np.uint8)
array([190, 211,  68, 242, 127, 211,  68, 242, 163, 109, 227,  68, 242,
       127, 211,  68, 112, 139,  68, 212,  68, 242, 127, 211,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0, 248, 127,  24, 135, 204, 241, 127, 211,  68,
       242, 163, 109, 227,  68, 242, 127, 211,  68, 112, 139,  68, 212,
        68, 242, 127, 211,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 248, 127, 189,
       211,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
       248, 127], dtype=uint8)
```